# How to make a falling curtain effect like this in CSS

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

How do you make an effect like this. I'm pretty new in **CSS animations** and I don't actually know where to start. I do now this, it's a hover so you'll probably need a transition to trigger the effect. I also know the photo should have a static position and the blue div should have a relative position. From here on, I have no idea where to start. Anyone who can help me out? Thanks!

[image: GIF]

Comment: Make us see what effort have you actually put in trying to accomplish this. We'll help you out from there.

Comment: I actually really have no clue how I could make this kind of effect, really shouldn't asked otherwise. I tried some things with these transistion-property and also transisition-timing-function and delay. I just don't know how I can set the left corner as starting point and create the effect itself

Comment: why chose scary image?

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal It's the only gif I found of it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really try to learn and tweak it around and try to come up with it on your own but here's this anyways.Hope, this helps.

```css
#a,
#b {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}

#b {
  opacity: 0;
  background: blue;
  transform: rotate(100deg);
}

#a:hover #b {
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform-style: preserve-3D;
  transition: transform 2s linear;
  animation: mymove 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will help for sure! Thanks for your time & effort. Really appreciate it! I can learn a lot from this!

Comment: @LucasVerhoest Don't forget to mark the answer. Cheers and happy learning :)

Comment: Did it! :) Thanks again!

Comment: Allah yolunda :)

Answer (score 3):

I hope this helps you.

```css
.img_wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.img_wrap img {
  width: 100%;
}
.img_details {
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
@keyframes elastic {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.overlay {    
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.img_wrap:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform-style: preserve-3D;
  transition: transform 1.5s linear;
  animation: elastic 1.5s forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="img_wrap">
<img src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/52597142?wid=520&hei=520&fmt=pjpeg" />
<div class="img_details">
<span class="left">Santa toy</span>
<span class="right">3$</span>
</div>
<div class="overlay">
<span>Sold out</span>
</div>
</div>
```